# Floating Button Animation Doesn't Work In UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

please help me regarding floating button animation doesn't working properly in UITableViewController. Below I attached the video and code for better understand, I'm using this library for floating button https://github.com/gizmoboy7/VCFloatingActionButton :

Video :
 https://youtu.be/m-ivFXjXLOM

Code :

```
CGRect floatButtonFrame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 44 - 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 44 - 20, 44, 44);


    floatingButton = [[VCFloatingActionButton alloc] initWithFrame:floatButtonFrame normalImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus"] andPressedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"] withScrollview:self.aktivitiTableView];

    floatingButton.imageArray = @[@"fb-icon",@"twitter-icon",@"google-icon",@"linkedin-icon"];
    floatingButton.labelArray = @[@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"Google Plus",@"Linked in"];

    floatingButton.hideWhileScrolling = NO;
    floatingButton.delegate = self;

    [self.aktivitiTableView addSubview:floatingButton];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've added your button to the `UITableView`.
The `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass so by doing this, you've actually added the button into the scroll views bounds hence why it moves when you scroll the table view (changing the `contentOffset`).

Instead, you want to add it to the table view's superview however if you are actually using `UITableViewController` then `self.view` == `self.tableView`. You *could* add it to `self.tableView.superview` however its out of your view controllers scope so its not something i'd recommend you do.

You either want to add it from the containing view controller implementation (if you have access to it), embed the `UITableViewController` within a parent `UIViewController` or change your view controller implementation to subclass from `UIViewController` and then add the table view as a subview to `self.view` yourself.

Thats the proper way to do things anyway.